# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use') Tatum SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, sdk

This is my code to signAndBroadcast the transaction

```
import { TatumSDK, Network, BinanceSmartChain } from "@tatumio/tatum";
import { EvmWalletProvider } from "@tatumio/evm-wallet-provider";

async function bsc() {
    const tatumSdk = await TatumSDK.init < BinanceSmartChain > ({
        network: Network.BINANCE_SMART_CHAIN_TESTNET,
        apiKey: { v4: "!!!API_KEY!!!" },
        configureWalletProviders: [EvmWalletProvider],
    });

    const payload = {
        privateKey: "!!!PRIVATE_KEY!!!",
        to: "!!!TO!!!",
        value: "0.1",
        maxPriorityFeePerGas: "10",
        maxFeePerGas: "10",
    };

    console.log(tatumSdk.walletProvider);

    const txHash = await tatumSdk.walletProvider
        .use(EvmWalletProvider)
        .signAndBroadcast(payload);

    console.log(txHash);
    await tatumSdk.destroy();
}

bsc();
```

When I try to run this code I'm getting

```
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')
    at bsc (e:\Work Software\XAMPP\xampp_php_8\htdocs\BitxeAPI\test.js:22:10)
    at <anonymous> (e:\Work Software\XAMPP\xampp_php_8\htdocs\BitxeAPI\test.js:29:1)
    at run (internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
```

I'm using the latest Tatum SDK as per my debugging issue is with this line of code.

```
.use(EvmWalletProvider)
```

I debugged the code and searched on google but didn't found any solution.

Comment: I don't see that part of code in your shared code. Share all code where .use(EvmWalletProvider) is writed

Comment: I have shared all my code 

    "const txHash = await tatumSdk.walletProvider
        .use(EvmWalletProvider)
        .signAndBroadcast(payload);"

this is the code which is using ".use(EvmWalletProvider)"